# How to make sharing icon in one row?

Tags: html, css

I am really bad with css and html, can somebody help with this simply problem?
On the bottom of the [site][1] i have text and sharing icons. How can i make them in one row? Like on right from text. It looks horrible now. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here:

this css should work:

```
.text-muted {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.ya-share2 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

explain: it makes both elements able to coexist in the same line, plus the margin-top is just for aligning it.

add that to your CSS file and youre good to go

Comment: oh, and the "float: right" makes them jump to the right of the footer... giving better looking. If i did help, please vote me up and mark my answer as the solving one. Thank you and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Going to upvote you in minute. Have to wait!